# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings,log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar,slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I'm getting the following error. It seems there are multiple logging frameworks bound to sl4j. Not sure how to resolve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
14:42:35,411 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
14:42:35,412 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) SLF4J: Found binding in [vfs:/content/offer-warehouse-processor-api.war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
14:42:35,412 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-3) SLF4J: Found binding in [vfs:/content/offer-warehouse-processor-api.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you that you have both slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar and log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar on your classpath. slf4j-log4j12 routes all SLF4J logging to log4j 1.2. Log4j-sfl4j-impl routes all logging to log4j 2. You need to remove the one you don't want. For example, if you want to use log4j 2 then remove slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar from your project. If you aren't sure how it got included and your are using Maven then run

```
mvn dependency:tree >mvn.txt
```

and then look in the mvn.txt file that was created and find where the jar is being included and what dependency it is under from your pom.xml. Then add an exclusion like

```
<exclusions>
  <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

in the dependency that is including it.